# Formatting Usage with Docopt

Tags: python, docopt

I am having a problem with my usage statements in docopt.

This is how I'd expect usage to work in the script. The optional parameters (defined with []), I would like to be able to use them together or individually. So `-t -o` or `-o` or `-t` should be valid. At the moments I cant use `-o` without `-t`.
If i use pipe `|` to separate them I can't use both at the same time. I've tried various combinations. I cant seem to get it work as id like. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

```
"""
Description:

Script does stuff

Usage:
  script.py (-d <ditem>) (-u <uitem>) (-p <pitem>) (-s <sfile>) [-t <tfile>] [-o <ofile>] [-v]
  script.py (-d <ditem>) (-l) [-t <tfile>] [-o <ofile>] [-v]
  script.py -h | --help
  script.py --version

Options:
  -v --verbose       Does stuff
  -t --tfile         Does stuff
  -o --output        Does stuff
  -l --litem         Does stuff
  -u --uitem         Does stuff
  -p --pitem         Does stuff
  -d --ditem         Does stuff
  -s --sitem         Does stuff
  -h --help          Show this screen.
  --version          Show version.
  """
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by using the following:

By adding the usage strings `script.py (-d <ditem>) (-l) ([-t <tfile>] | [-o <ofile>]) [-v]` and another `script.py (-d <ditem>) (-l) [-t <tfile>] [-o <ofile>] [-v]` means I can use `-t` and `-o` independently or `-t -o` together. However Im not able to use them in this order `-o -t`.

```
Description:

Script does stuff

Usage:
  script.py (-d <ditem>) (-u <uitem>) (-p <pitem>) (-s <sfile>) [-t <tfile>] [-o <ofile>] [-v]
  script.py (-d <ditem>) (-l) ([-t <tfile>] | [-o <ofile>]) [-v]
  script.py (-d <ditem>) (-l) [-t <tfile>] [-o <ofile>] [-v]
  script.py -h | --help
  script.py --version
```

Answer (score 0):

[To allow `-t` along, `-o` along, `-t` and `-o` together](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Script+does+stuff.%0D%0A%0D%0AUsage%3A%0D%0A+++script.py+%5B-t%5D+%5B-o%5D+%0D%0A%0D%0AOptions%3A%0D%0A++-t+--tfile+++++++++Does+stuff%0D%0A++-o+--output++++++++Does+stuff%0D%0A&argv=-o):

```
Script does stuff.

Usage:
   script.py [-t] [-o] 

Options:
  -t --tfile         Does stuff
  -o --output        Does stuff
```

[If it is an error when both `-t` and `-o` are absent](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Script+does+stuff.%0D%0A%0D%0AUsage%3A%0D%0A+++script.py+-t%0D%0A+++script.py+-o%0D%0A+++script.py+-t+-o%0D%0A%0D%0AOptions%3A%0D%0A++-t+--tfile+++++++++Does+stuff%0D%0A++-o+--output++++++++Does+stuff%0D%0A&argv=):

```
Script does stuff.

Usage:
   script.py -t
   script.py -o
   script.py -t -o

Options:
  -t --tfile         Does stuff
  -o --output        Does stuff
```

Comment: ive resolved this already thank you. My answer above fixes it but I cant accept my answer as an answer unfortunately

Comment: @iNoob: [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22787398/4279) contains contradictory usage e.g., `(a | b)` on one line and just `a b` on another.